# Implementing ACS on emulator web application

Tags: c#, azure, acs

Can we implement `Access Control Service ( ACS )` without Log on into the

`Windows Azure Management Portal`.Means can we implement ACS on window azure emulator web

application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access Control Service, the name says it all. This is a service that's being provided by Microsoft which you can use. This means you can have an application hosted on-premises, in the cloud or even in the emulator and it will still work fine with ACS.

Now, if you want to 'run' ACS in the emulator (I think this is what you're asking) then the answer is no. You cannot 'run' ACS in the emulator. I suggest you simply use the real ACS service (even for development) since its very cheap.

If for some reason you can't get an account (maybe Azure is not supported in your country) you could try using the labs environment: https://portal.appfabriclabs.com/Default.aspx (if I'm correct you don't need a credit card to use this).

And since ACS is simply based on standards you could replace it with something else for local development, like the great [IdentityServer](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/) (supports WS-Trust, WS-Federation, OAuth2, WRAP ...)

Answer (score -1):

The Windows Azure Platform Training Kit ([Course](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_introtoacs2_topic2)) shows how to develop using ACS in the Compute Emulator.