# Test Azure Service Bus Queues Locally with a subscription

Tags: .net, azure, asp.net-core, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

How does one test Azure Service Bus Queues Locally?

1.I have to rename our Queue to something else, as some other developers or already running function may consume it

```
Example: 

a) Original Queue: Product

b) Test Queue: Test
```

2.We also have Azure functions picking up queues, so also rename the Service Bus Trigger.

However, its still not working?

Does Anything else need to be changed?

I see Queue messages being sent with Service Bus Explorer, but they are not being event handle or responded with our process action.

```
[FunctionName(nameof(TestAsync))]
public async Task TestRollAsync(
[ServiceBusTrigger("test", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = false)] Message sbMessage)
{
    var cmessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sbMessage.Body);
    Test msg = null;

    try
    {
        msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(cmessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming the queue is not the most convenient way as it will require to undo the changes when you commit the code and that's error-prone. A better option would be to use a developer-specific Azure Service Bus namespace that can be provisioned on a standard tier, using MSDN/company account. You can have as many namespaces on the standard tier as needed. There's no cost involved for the service other than $10 a month for the service (or the equivalent for your currency) when additional namespaces are provisioned and not used.

With a namespace per developer, your code stays as-is, and the connection string (the value) can be changed in the `settings.json` file that is local and should not be committed to the repository. That way the queue name and connection string name remain untouched and you can develop/debug locally

Comment: wouldn't renaming namespaces be as inconvenient as renaming queue names? just curious, thanks

Comment: all I do to rename a queue is Ctrl-R-R in Visual Studio,  wouldn't I have to do the same for namespaces?

Comment: A namespace cannot be renamed. Only provisioned. A namespace per environment/developer would no require anything other than a file that would not be committed anyways.

Comment: When you deal with a single queue, not an issue. But in a more sophisticated system, having consistency in queue names between environments is invaluable.

Answer (score 1):

1.Rename the Queue to something else, as some other developers or already running function may consume it. (and Azure namespaces are not setup, as listed here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63527807/12425844)

Example:

a) Original Queue: Product

b) Test Queue: Test

2.We also have Azure functions picking up queues, so also rename the Service Bus Trigger.

```
[ServiceBusTrigger("test", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = false)] Message sbMessage)
{
```

3.Make sure Azure Functions is also running in the solution.

4.Create an Azure Functions local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"   
  },
  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```